# My Navigation Bar will not appear clear.

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

My navigation Bar will not appear clear. I have the code below in my viewdid load. This code works in other view controllers but for some reason this current view controller still shows a white translucent bar on top. Not sure why this would work on some pages and not others. The NSLog prints UIDeviceWhiteColorSpace 0 0, which I know means clear. There are bar buttons on the navigation bar and I need them to stay, or else I would of just completely hid that navigation bar. Any tips on why this would happen, or other ways to have a clear navigation bar. Thank you.

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.shadowImage = [UIImage new];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
self.navigationController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
NSLog(@"color: %@", self.navigationController.view.backgroundColor);
NSLog(@"color: %@", self.navigationController.navigationBar.backgroundColor);
```

Answer (score 1):

to apply a unified behavior to your `UINavigationController` allover the app, it is better to change its appearance once in app delegate

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    ....
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setShadowImage:[UIImage new]];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTranslucent:YES];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was putting the code into the `viewWillAppear` instead of `viewDidLoad`. Some view controllers need the navigation bar as full opacity and some needed it to be clear. Overall I got what I needed. Thank you!